# Sending google map link through GSM network using Arduino uno

Tags: arduino, gsm

Can anyone tell me how I can send the following arduino code, in a single SMS message via GSM network

```
Serial.print("http://maps.google.com/?q=");
latitude();
Serial.print(',');
longitude();
```

Comment: Hello user3286992, welcome to StackOverflow.  Do I understand correctly that you want to send an SMS from an Arduino?

Comment: you need a GSM shield, library and code depends on witch model you'll choose.